# How to build Unity with Vuforia for desktop and use Webcam as video input?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, image-recognition

So I need to track some objects over space using two webcams. After many many failed attempts with different Python libraries and framewirks like OpenCV and trying very old and poorly mantained examples, I figured out I would track the images using a well known tool for me that has always worked good: Vuforia.

The problem is that before I had used Vuforia building for Android devices, and that works like a charm. The thing is that know I want to execute it from a Desktop computer (Windows or Ubuntu). While in the editor, everything works excellent and my program does the job perfectly. But when I want to build and then execute the .exe provided by unity, I loose the ability to use my webcam, so it gets useless.

I did some research in Vuforia documentation pages and read that they do not support desktop for Windows with Unity. I FULLY UNDERSTAND THIS. The thing is I want to see if there's a "hacky" way of getting away with this, since the program in the editor runs well, why could'nt it just do the same in the executable version?

Thanks in advance, I hope I can find a way.